# Writing SQLite results to a list/dictionary in Python

Tags: python, sql, list, sqlite, dictionary

Thanks for looking.

I'm trying to write multiple results from an SQLite query into either a list or dictionary (somewhere where I can use the data in Python).

The code I have is:

```
cursor = conn.execute("select * from members where MEMBERSHIP_DATE <= DATE('now','-1 years', '-1 day')")
    for row in cursor:
        print("ID = ", row[0])
        print ("NAME = ", row[1])
        print ("AGE =", row[2])
        print ("ADDRESS = ", row[3])
        print ("MEMBERSHIP = ", row[4])
        print ("MEMBERSHIP_DATE =", row[5], "\n")
        results = [{'ID': row[0], 'NAME': row[1], 'AGE': row[2], 'ADDRESS': row[3], 'MEMBERSHIP': row[4], 'MEMBERSHIP_DATE': row[5]} for row in cursor.fetchall()]
        print (results)
```

My program is returning two results, however the following happens:
It prints out result 1
It stores result 2 in the dictionary.

```
ID =  1
NAME =  joe bloggs
AGE = 33
ADDRESS =  18 benwell drive
MEMBERSHIP =  full
MEMBERSHIP_DATE = 2016-04-30 

[{'MEMBERSHIP': 'child', 'ID': 2, 'MEMBERSHIP_DATE': '2016-06-22', 'ADDRESS': '1 benwell drive', 'AGE': 12, 'NAME': 'sarah hart'}]
```

Does anyone know how I can output the SQL results and store each result in a format where I can then work with the data in Python? In my mind, I foresee a list/dictionary auto-created for each result (as the amount of results will be dynamic each day).

Ideally, the program will print all memberships over a certain date then store each one in a list/dictionary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take `results = [{'ID': row[0], 'NAME': row[1], 'AGE': row[2], 'ADDRESS': row[3], 'MEMBERSHIP': row[4], 'MEMBERSHIP_DATE': row[5]} for row in cursor.fetchall()]` out of the `for` loop. You're redefining the whole list on each iteration.

Comment: And once you do that, print results from this list and not on cursor.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to have an iterable with a dictionary, why not use the built-in `sqlite3.Row` [row factory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#row-objects)? You can access your data by index or by column name like you would in a dictionary.

Also, you should create a cursor object from the connection object and use the cursor for executing. When you execute a statement on a connection object, a cursor is implicitly created to handle the execute. As stated in the Zen of Python, explicit is better than implicit.